# Postgres optimizing in an "A OR exists(B)" query

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a lot of trouble with a particular case in my Postgres optimization.

Essentially, I have three tables, which will simplify as:

- `Place`: id, name (String), select (Boolean)
- `Bookmark`: id, user (Integer), place (Integer)
- `User`: id, name (String)

The `Place` table has several million rows (and growing), but a relatively small amount of them has `select` as true.

I have several indexes on these tables, obviously on all `id`, plus a partial one on `place where "select"=true`, and a unique one on the `bookmark` (user, place) combos. There are more, but I think they're not relevant here.

When I do a query of the type:

```
SELECT * 
FROM place 
WHERE "select" 
LIMIT 10;
```

it takes 3ms.

When I do a query of the type:

```
SELECT * 
FROM place 
WHERE exists (SELECT id 
              FROM bookmark 
              WHERE user IN (1,2,3,4) 
                AND bookmark.place = place.id) 
LIMIT 10;
```

it's also blazing fast.

However, if I do an `OR` on both conditions, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM place 
WHERE "select" 
   OR exists (SELECT id 
              FROM bookmark 
              WHERE user IN (1,2,3,4) 
                AND bookmark.place = place.id) 
LIMIT 10;
```

it slows down to over 1s.

Besides doing two queries in my code and combining the results, is there any way I can optimize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old problem, [`OR` is a performance killer](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/).

Use `UNION`:

```
(SELECT * FROM place
 WHERE select
 LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM place
 WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM bookmark
               WHERE user IN (1,2,3,4)
                 AND bookmark.place = place.id)
 LIMIT 10)
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!